# Offline MapBox with layers

Tags: android, mapbox-gl

Im writing an android app using MapBox(`com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.2.0-beta.1@aar`) with layers from a privet tile server that work online -

```
private void addLayer(String url, String sourceName, String layerName)
{

    String sourceId;

    RasterSource webMapSource = new RasterSource(
            sourceName,
            new TileSet("tileset", url));

    mMapboxMap.addSource(webMapSource);
    // Add the web map source to the map.
    RasterLayer webMapLayer = new RasterLayer(layerName, sourceName);
    mMapboxMap.addLayer(webMapLayer);
}
```

But I want it to work offline (I'm using `com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.offline.OfflineManager`) but offline I can see only the map without the Layers - how can I add them ?